# Missing order total Paypal express check out

Tags: paypal, salesforce, express-checkout

i'm trying to make SOAP call using Salesforce apex code to Paypal express checkout API,
but i'm facing this problem missing order total , also i'm sure that i put the order total within my SOAP call , here's my SOAP call form:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
      <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <Username>xxx</Username>
        <Password>xxx</Password>
        <Signature>xxx</Signature>
      </Credentials>
    </RequesterCredentials>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SetExpressCheckoutReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
      <SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
        <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">78</Version>
        <SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
          <ReturnURL>www.success.com</ReturnURL>
          <CancelURL>www.cancel.com</CancelURL>
          <OrderTotal currencyID="USD">1</OrderTotal>
        </SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>            
      </SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
    </SetExpressCheckoutReq>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , it's in the SOAP

```
  string doExpressCheckout = '';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:urn1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Header>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:RequesterCredentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Credentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Username>'+un+'</urn1:Username>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Password>'+pw+'</urn1:Password>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Signature>'+sig+'</urn1:Signature>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:Credentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:RequesterCredentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Header>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Body>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Version>'+version+'</urn1:Version>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Token>'+token+'</urn1:Token>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:PayerID>'+payerID+'</urn1:PayerID>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:PaymentDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:OrderTotal currencyID="'+UsedCurrency+'">'+amount+'</urn1:OrderTotal>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:PaymentDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Body>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```